OpenCV CMake Configuration: Java Support Not Detected (JAVA: NO)"
Question
I am trying to build OpenCV (version 4.10.0) with Java support on Windows, but during the CMake configuration, the output indicates that Java support is not detected (Java: NO). Cmake version:3.30.3
Here are the details of my setup and what I’ve tried:
Environment

OpenCV version: 4.10.0
CMake version: 3.30.3
Java version: JDK 17
Operating System: Windows 10

Question
What could be causing CMake to not detect Java support in OpenCV, and how can I resolve this issue?
Steps Taken

I have verified that Java is installed correctly by running:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\javac.exe" -version



The output confirms that Java is installed.

I ran the following CMake command:
cmake -DWITH_JAVA=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_opencv_java=ON -DJAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17" -DCMAKE_JAVA_COMPILER="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin/javac.exe" -DCMAKE_JAVA_EXECUTABLE="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/bin/java.exe" -DJNI_INCLUDE_PATH="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include/win32" -DJAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include" -DJAVA_AWT_LIBRARY="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/lib/jawt.lib" ..

The output from CMake includes:
--   Java:
--     ant:                         C:/myProjects/ANT_INSTALL_DIR/apache-ant-1.10.13/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.10.13)
--     Java:                        NO
--     JNI:                         C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include/win32 C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-17/include


Attempts to Resolve

I checked my JAVA_HOME environment variable, and it is set correctly.
I tried running CMake with different configurations and paths, but I still see Java: NO.

